# Determining the disc of convergence in two series and determining at which points on the boundary of the disc the series converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

The two series are as follows:

$f(z) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty n(z+1-i)^{2n}$

and

$f(z) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-1}z^{n}$

I have worked out that the discs of convergence are, respectively:

$z:|z+(1-i)|^{2} < 1$ and $z:|z| \le 1, z \ne 1$

But finding the points on these boundaries for which the functions converge is a complete mystery to me!

Comment: You've used strict and non-strict inequalities when describing the discs of convergence. Is that not because you've shown/disproved convergence along the boundary of their respective discs?

Comment: I'm not sure that the second one is convergent everywhere on the disc. Certainly it's not convergent at z = 1. Wasn't so sure about the first one, so left it as a closed interval just incase

Comment: Since I have to go, I'll just leave you with this hint for now: your domains of convergence were exactly right! Can you prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Your open discs are correct.

Let us begin with $\sum _{n \ge 1} \frac 1 n z^n$ for $z$ on the circle $|z|=1$. We shall use [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Notice that $(\frac 1 n) _{n \ge 1}$ is a decreasing sequence tending to $0$, and that for $z \ne 1$ we have

$$\left| \sum _{n = 1} ^N z^n \right| = \left| \frac {1 - z^{N+1}} {1-z} - 1 \right| \le \frac {1 + |z^{N+1}|} {|1-z|} + 1 = \frac 2 {|1-z|} + 1 ,$$

a bound which is independent of $N$. Then Dirichlet's test does the rest of the job for us, telling us that the series converges for every $z$ as above. Clearly, the series diverges for $z=1$.

For the series $\sum _{n \ge 1} n (z+1 - \Bbb i) ^{2n}$ and $z$ on the circle $|z+1 - \Bbb i| = 1$, let $t = z + 1 - \Bbb i$; clearly if $t = 1$ the series diverges. Let us assume then that $t \ne 1$. Then

$$\sum _{n = 1} ^N n t^n = t \sum _{n = 1} ^N n t^{n-1} = t \left( \sum _{n = 1} ^N t^n \right)' = t \left( \sum _{n = 0} ^N t^n - 1 \right)' = t \left( \sum _{n = 0} ^N t^n \right)' = t \left( \frac {1 - t^{N+1}} {1-t} \right)' = \\
t \frac {-(N+1)t^N (1-t) + (1-t^{N+1})} {(1-t)^2} = \frac t {(1-t)^2} \Big( N t^{N+1} - (N+1) t^N + 1 \Big) .$$

Let us show that $N t^{N+1} - (N+1) t^N$ has no limit for $N \to \infty$ when $|t|=1$ and $t \ne 1$. Assume that $N t^{N+1} - (N+1) t^N \to l$; this means that there exist $N_1$ such that

$$\left| N t^{N+1} - (N+1) t^N - l \right| < 1$$

for $N \ge N_1$, so if we divide by $(N+1) t^N$ we get

$$\left| \frac N {N+1} t - 1 - \frac l {(N+1) t^N}\right| < \frac 1 {N+1} ,$$

for $N \ge N_1$, whence if we let $N \to \infty$ we get

$$|t - 1| \le 0$$

which is impossible since we have assumed $t \ne 1$.

It follows that $\sum _{n = 1} ^N n t^n$ has no limit either, so it is divergent.

To conclude, the first series converges on $\{ |z + 1 -  \Bbb i| < 1 \}$ and the second one on $\{ |z| \le 1 \} \setminus \{1\}$.